# ASP.net display information periodically from onClick function

Tags: asp.net, button, onclick, wait

The problem is when the button is pressed all the data is display to the text box at once. I have tried thread.sleep which did not work the way I wanted. The button is only pressed once. Can anyone please point me into the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Like so

I eat an apple.
I eat a pear.
I eat a peach.

I would Like this

I eat an apple.
wait a second

I eat a pear.
wait a second

I eat a peach.
wait a second.

Answer (score 0):

I assume with "asp.net", you mean an Asp.net webforms application.
You cannot do this in from the server-side / code-behind. When the user clicks a button it triggers a postback, which means the click, including all form-values are send to the server. The server then creates a new webpage that it sends back to the client as a return to the post.

So the thread.sleep only slows down the server. It takes longer before the client receives the new page.

Back to hour question. The best way to do what you want is by javascript in the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with server-side code ( like you have tried Thread.Sleep),  as already explained in above answer too!. So i am going to give javascript example for this.

Note: You can replace  button, textbox with `asp:button` and `asp:textbox` used in this example.

```js
var texts = ["I eat an apple. wait a second",
  "I eat a pear. wait a second",
  "I eat a peach. wait a second."
];

var counter = 0;
var to_tim;

function ShowData() {
  alert("wait for 1 sec., it will start automatically");
  to_tim = setInterval(function() {
    OnShowData()
  }, 1000);
}

function OnShowData() {
  if (counter == 3) {
    StopText();
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById("txt").value = texts[counter];
  counter++;
}

function StopText() {
  clearInterval(to_tim);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" readonly="readonly" />

<input type="button" id="btn" value="initiate" onclick="ShowData();" />
```

Comment: If I have custom classes within the app _ code folder. Can I access them from the javascript file. Or can I return an object back to the on click within cs file.

Comment: You can define a method(say abc() ) in code behind , and invoke that custom class from that method, using webmethod, jquery to invoke ABC() - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx